# Write a program that encrypts lines by swapping pairs of characters java

Tags: java

Following are some Examples:

```
Original line          Encrypted line
abcdef                badcfe
The jelly bean        hT eejll yebna
cde                   dce
```

Your program must keep prompting the user to enter a line to be encrypted, display the encrypted
line, and continue this way until the user enter (exactly) "exit".

Here's my program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab6Q2Encryption
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a line: ");
        while (kb.hasNext()){
            String line = kb.nextLine();
            String encryptedLine ="";
            // swap pairs of characters
            for (int i=1; i<line.length(); i+=2) {
                encryptedLine += line.charAt(i);
                encryptedLine += line.charAt(i-1);
            }
            // if odd number of characters
            // then append the last character
            if (line.length()%2 == 1)
                encryptedLine += line.charAt(line.length()-1);
            //
            System.out.println(encryptedLine+"<--encrypted line");
            System.out.println("Enter a line: ");
        }
        System.out.println("Program ending due to end-of-file");
    }
}
```

I am stuck with the part of ending the loop. How can i let that the user end the loop by entering "exit"?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
        ...
        while (kb.hasNext()){
            String line = kb.nextLine();
            if (line.equals("exit")) break; // inserted line
            String encryptedLine ="";
        ...
```